# Problems with DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I'm in charge of the admin of the VPS of the company I'm working. Basically, those VPS host our websites and also serve as name servers for the domain names we purchased. To manage all this, I'm using ISPConfig 3 on Linux debian Wheezy machines.

The problem is that we purchased some domain names at our registrar and asked him to point those names to our VPS. Then on the VPS, with the help of ISPConfig I added the zones for each purchased domain, mentioning the host name of our registrar's name servers. But the domain name is not working. When I try to ping after setup, I get : "unknown host etaxe.bj" error (one of the domain names is etaxe.bj). The registrar confirmed that he pointed the domain name to my VPS IP address. So the problem may be at my side. As I'm very newbie in managing DNS zone, I'd like to know what I can do to first find where is the problem and try to solve it. How to troubleshoot DNS zone issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nameservers for your domain are not valid.

Currently they are set to:

```
Name Server: ns1.hesystems.group.com
Name Server: ns2.hesystems.group.com
```

But neither of these actually exists.

```
$ host ns1.hesystems.group.com
Host ns1.hesystems.group.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
$ host ns2.hesystems.group.com
Host ns2.hesystems.group.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

You need to set these correctly at your registrar.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Hampton. I'm going to ask my registrar to check it for me. Normally, it should be ns1.hesystems-group.com. But please, can you tell me how you found that these are the actually set nameservers for my domain ?

Comment: I just looked at your whois record.